# How to Iterate Map values inside BaseAdapter's GetView() method?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, baseadapter

I am trying to parse the following Json.

```
{
"effect_list": [{
      "1":[  
         {  
            "effects_id":"1",
            "effects_name":"Band 1"
         },
         {  
            "effects_id":"2",
            "effects_name":"Band 2"
         }


      ],
      "2": [ 
         {  
            "effects_id":"4",
            "effects_name":"Background Blur"
         },
         {  
            "effects_id":"5",
            "effects_name":"Blemish Removal"
         }
      ] 
   }]
}
```

My BaseAdapter shows only first Item in the ListView. I am trying to retrieve values in Map. During iteration the values gets override.When I print the values, It's printing properly.

**MyContactAdapter2.java**

```
public class MyContactAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
        List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> contactList;
        Context context;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;


        // Constructors
        public MyContactAdapter2(Context context, List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> objects) {

            this.context = context;
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            contactList = objects;
        }

        public MyContactAdapter2() {
            System.out.println("hai");
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            int count = contactList.size();
            System.out.println("Count size" + count);
            return count;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, List<EffectList>> getItem(int position) {
            return contactList.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            System.out.println(10);


            final MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder vh;
            if (convertView == null) {
                View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.get_layout_row_view, parent, false);
                vh = MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
                view.setTag(vh);

            } else {
                vh = (MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }





            for (Map<String, List<EffectList>> map : contactList) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<EffectList>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    Object value = entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println("key :" + key + "value :" + value);

                        EffectList item = getItem(position).get(key).get(0);

                        vh.textViewName.setText(item.getEffectsId());
                        vh.textViewEmail.setText(item.getEffectsName());

                }
            }


            return vh.rootView;
        }


        private static class ViewHolder {
            public final RelativeLayout rootView;
            public final ImageView imageView;
            public final TextView textViewName;
            public final TextView textViewEmail;

            private ViewHolder(RelativeLayout rootView, ImageView imageView, TextView textViewName, TextView textViewEmail) {
                this.rootView = rootView;
                this.imageView = imageView;
                this.textViewName = textViewName;
                this.textViewEmail = textViewEmail;
            }

            public static MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder create(RelativeLayout rootView) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                TextView textViewName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
                TextView textViewEmail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
                return new MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder(rootView, imageView, textViewName, textViewEmail);
            }
        }
    }
```

**So my Question is, how can I iterate the "Map" values inside "GetView()" in "BaseAdapter"?**

Is it possible to iterate values inside **GetView()** method in BaseAdapter?

Comment: does this run OK?

Comment: yes, Run's without error

Comment: it is possible to iterate a map inside getView() but don't too much it could slow your app

Comment: Can you please give me a solution for the problem in above code?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you do:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // ... blah blah ...

    final Map<String, List<EffectList>> effectMap = getItem(position);

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<EffectList>> entry : effectMap.entrySet()) {
        final String key = entry.getKey();
        final List<EffectList> value = entry.getValue();
        // ... do stuff ...
    }

    // ... blah blah 
}
```

?

Comment: I am getting error **Error:(147, 58) error: for-each not applicable to expression type required: array or java.lang.Iterable found:    Map<String,List<EffectList>>**

Comment: compile time error. **Error:(148, 41) error: cannot find symbol method getKey() and getValue()**

Comment: @user7357013 did you write `Map.Entry` and not just `Map`?  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey() and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue()

Comment: It print's the value correctly, but displays only the first Item in Listview.

Comment: And my getCount() size is always 1.

Comment: Perhaps you want to iterate over `contactList` in an outer loop, instead of calling `getItem()`?